# Convert date-time format in float

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, plot, imshow

[image]

these data are of type: pandas.core.series.Series
how can I convert to float values so that I can display them on the axis of a plot?

[image]

I want to display the time in the x axis in this plot that i got with imshow.

Comment: `.astype('float64')`?

Comment: @SergeBallesta may i ask you better how i could use it?

Comment: Start with Numpy's [Datetimes and Timedeltas](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.datetime.html).

Comment: If you had provided copyable code instead of an image, you would have got an answer... More seriously, an image adds nothing here, and prevent to know the name of the variable containing the series, so I cannot give you any code.

Comment: Why do you have to convert them to float just to display on a plot? `plt` works well with `datetime64`.

Comment: @QuangHoang how can i display this data in the x axis of a plot?

Comment: `plt.plot(time_series, some_data)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang I have a csv file with values of quotas, time and signal intensity. I have to plot the heights in y, the time in the x and the intensities go to form a matrix. i use imshow to view.
how can i explain my problem to you?

Comment: `plt.scatter(df['time'], df['quotas'], c=df['intensity'], cmap='hot')`.

Comment: You don't do `imshow` on float coordinates. Another option is `countourf`.

Comment: Please create a [reprex] and see [ask].

Comment: @QuangHoang I added a graph to explain

Answer (score 1):

If your dates are in string format you can convert them to `datetime` and use `timestamp` method to get your date in the float format:

```py
from datetime import datetime

date_str = '2021-04-02 12:10:00'
dt = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

print(dt.timestamp())
```

If they already come in `datetime` type, then simply use `timestamp` method.

Output:

```
1617347400.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The `datetime64[ns]` dtype is internally an integer value of the number of nanoseconds since the epoch (1970-01-01T00:00:00)

If you only want to get that (large) integer as an integer or floating point value, you can do:

```
time_str_int = time_str.astype('int64')
```

or

```
time_str_float = time_str.astype('float64')
```

If you want a floating point number of days since a specific date (say `initial_date`), you could do:

```
time_str_days = (time_str - pd.Timestamp(initial_date)).astype('float64')/(24*3600*1000000000)
```